# Oracle SQL how to make a number 279429429489284928942 to 279429429489284.928942 using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

how to make a number 279429429489284928942 to 279429429489284.928942  6 decimal point for all values in the column

Comment: Simply divide `/ 1000000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try

```
SELECT 279429429489284928942/POWER(10,6) FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the column data type is some sort of float and that you actually want to change the values in the table, how about:

```
Update <table> 
SET <column> = <column> * .000001
```

?